# How to store the result object of a query into an object variable in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using this query to select all records from the `products` table and I want to store them inside an object variable which later I can use it for other purposes, so I tried this

```
 var SelectQuery = "Select * FROM `products`";
 var ProductDetails = {};
 conn.query(SelectQuery, function (err, result) {
     if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        ProductDetails = result;
      }
 });

 console.log(ProductDetails);
```

But in Console I get this `{}`.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to move your console.log(ProductDetails) into the else block above for this to display the results?

Comment: Ryan Wilson is correct-- you are looking at the code as if it executes line by line, but that is not quite correct-- the function passed as the second argument to `query` is a callback, and will only execute after the query has completed.  Meanwhile the code outside that will continue to run in order.  So what is happening in your code above is that you are console logging `ProductDetails` before the `result` has actually been assigned to it.

Comment: I get the result but I need a way to access to result's records out of the function block

Comment: Well, you either need to put whatever behavior you need into a function that is called from within the callback, or to leverage a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or leverage [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) -- but note that that is not natively available in all browsers.

Comment: @AlexanderNied
I know this I can have the result's records in the console if I place the console.log(result) inside the function, but I need the result's records outside the function

Comment: @a.Sahel -- see my above comment.  When dealing with asynchronous code, you have a pretty well defined tool set for handling it-- [callback pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).  Maybe somebody else can think of another approach, but I think this about covers it.

Comment: Can you provide an example

Answer (score 0):

*(Thanks to user [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) for pointing out a major oversight in my original answer)*

***If* `conn.query` is returning a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)** then you could make this work in the manner you are describing by using [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
async function getProducts() {
     var SelectQuery = "Select * FROM `products`";
     var ProductDetails = {};
     await conn.query(SelectQuery, function(err, result) {
         if (err) {
             console.log(err);
         } else {
             ProductDetails = result;
         }
     });    

    console.log(ProductDetails);
}
```

But note this *only works if your `conn.query` returns a promise.* Also, it is a newer ES feature, so you may need to transpile it depending on your node version.  Also, note that the function this takes place in will need to be wrapped with `async`.

Otherwise, the other candidates to leverage for handling asynchronicity are [callback functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) and [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

If `conn.query` does *not* return a promise, you could write your own query implementation that would return a promise so you could leverage `async`/`await`:

```
function asyncQuery(sqlQuery) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        conn.query(SelectQuery, function(err, result) {
             if (err) {
                 reject(err);
             } else {
                 resolve(result);
             }
         })
    })
}
```

Then the original function could be rewritten as:

```
async function getProducts() {
    var SelectQuery = "Select * FROM `products`";
    var ProductDetails = await asyncQuery(SelectQuery);
    console.log(ProductDetails);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any evidence that `conn.query()` returns a promise, particularly when passed a callback?  I rather doubt it and thus `await` would not wait for the async operation to be done.  `await` only waits on a promise, nothing else.

Comment: @jfriend00 -- _excellent_ point.  I've grown accustomed to asynchronous functions returning promises as a matter of course, but I am absolutely just presuming that this is the case.  I'll edit the answer accordingly.  Thanks for calling that out.

Comment: @Alexander Nied 
it gives me this error in the console `Promise { <pending> }`